# What is a good cross platform Java web server for development?

Tags: java, javascript, webserver

My team is developing javascript apps; and uses a mixture of Windows & Mac dev machines.

I'm looking for a simple local webserver to be used during development that allows serving of static resources from a specific directory

In the windows world [CassiniDev](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/) would be perfect; or in the Unix world [Python's SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html) would also work.

Ideally I'd like something similar written in Java (but not forcing all the servlet stuff on you)

Comment: Might be a better question for Programmers SE.

Comment: What's wrong with the Apache HTTP server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) is a great option if you want something written in Java.  It is a servlet container too, but very lightweight.  I'm not sure why you need something written in Java though if it's just serving static content.

If you're looking for a bit of fun in developing your web server why not take a look at [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/) - it will run on all types of machine and serve your static content fast, if you write a simple JavaScript program to serve the files (or use a pre-written one).

Comment: How can I start Jetty from the command line and have it point at a specific existing folder?  (one which doesn't contain all the servlet stuff)

Comment: @David Laing it does now.  See 3b for link to pre built Windows binaries [https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation].  And to serve static content Jetty just needs a tiny config change [http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Static+Content]

Comment: That's exactly the info I needed.  BTW; you seem to have included extra ] in your links

Answer (score 1):

you can use tomcat.  if you put flat html in the webapps/ROOT directory of tomcat (whereever you install it to) it will serve up those pages for you.

If it really is just html, why not just go with straight up apache?  Just point its web root at the directories you want to serve from...

Comment: I'm looking for something I can install from the command line; and then point at various existing folders

Comment: on linux you can do that with soft links.  installing tomcat is as simple as unzipping it.

Answer (score 0):

Macs have a web server preinstalled. It's Apache, you only need to activate it in the System preferences. By default it serves the content of a subdirectory of your Users directory. Otherwise as others have suggested use Jetty or apache tomcat.

Comment: Can I start apache from the command line & have it serve a custom folder?

Comment: ofc but I reccomend to read the docs for that ... as I don'r know much about apache